# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row, REFERENCES `eav_attribute`

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, magento

I have read all the answer, however I am not a guru guy in things like that... I want to install magento database to my local computer host that runs on xampp, however I keep getting an error:

> SQL query:

-

> -
>   -- Constraints for table `catalog_eav_attribute`
>   -- ALTER TABLE `catalog_eav_attribute`   ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute`
>   (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE; MySQL said:
>   Documentation
>
> ## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`labas`.`#sql-e94_2a`, CONSTRAINT
>
> `FK_CATALOG_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute`
>   (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE )

How could I solve this problem. Simple explanation would be awesome cause I have no clue in MySQL and SQL things at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because you're trying to add/update a row to `eav_attribute` that does not have a valid value for the `attribute_id` field based on the values currently stored in `catalog_eav_attribute`.

It's likely that `attribute_id` you're trying to reference in `eav_attribute` does simply not exist, therefor there's nothing to reference.

To diagnose the specific cause we'd need to see more code.

***Edit***

I ran across this query (and modifed it) that can help you to see ids that can be causing the issue:

```
SELECT c.attribute_id 
FROM catalog_eav_attribute c
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute e 
ON c.attribute_id = e.attribute_id
WHERE e.attribute_id IS NULL;
```